# Display the results in an alphabetical order, independently of their case

Tags: ls, sort, macos, case-sensitivity

I am using `ls` on MacOS 11.6.1. In the output, the Upper cases are displayed before the lower case. For example, I get the following output:

```
$ ls

Blabla.txt
GAGAS.txt
asdf.txt
blabla.txt
```

and would like to have instead:

```
$ ls

asdf.txt
blabla.txt
Blabla.txt
GAGAS.txt
```

Is this the normal default output of `ls`? How can I have the output number 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls` is required by POSIX to sort the file names in its output *according to the collating sequence in the current locale*.

If your system has no locale where the sort order ignores case at least in the first pass of comparing strings, you could try piping to `sort -f`:

```
ls -q | sort -f
```

(with the `-q` option to guarantee file names are displayed on one line by replacing control characters in them including newline with `?` (beware that may affect the order).

Or with the zsh shell, use something like:

```
lc() REPLY=$REPLY:l
print -rC1 -- *(o+lc)
```

Instead of `ls`. That is define a `lc` helper function that changes the value of `$REPLY` to lower case, and use that as an `o`rdering function for the glob expansion (not necessarily strictly equivalent to a case-insensitive comparison, but should be close enough especially for ASCII only text).